# Add and Remove Form Elements using HTML (Only)

Tags: html

At some point I seem to remember finding a way with *only* HTML to create a form element that could be duplicated or deleted, [similar to this](http://www.mredkj.com/tutorials/tableaddrow.html).

Is there any chance anybody knows what this is? Or was I dreaming?

Comment: HTML-only? So, client-side without JavaScript. Dream on.

Comment: Your example link does JavaScript to manipulate form's children, so you you must do in order to add / delete form members.

Comment: I know my link does it with Javascript, however I could swear I found some HTML5 Form way of doing it while browsing one day.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you wasn't dreaming.

This was part of [Webforms 2.0](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-forms/current-work/) and is implemented only in Opera (The feature is called [repetition model](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-forms/current-work/#repeatingFormControls)). But this feature was removed with HTML[5] forms (because to complicated), so you won't see this in any browser soon.